# How to get saved texts from saved file

Tags: vb6

I am making a number generator for my own purpose.
I already made it to work with these features:
 - Saves the generated number

What features I want :
 - When I close it loads the last generated number from the notepad.

here is the code:

```
Private Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\sto0007404\Documents\Numbers.txt"
Private CurrentNumber As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    CurrentNumber = CurrentNumber + 1
    txtRefNo.Text = "EM" & Format(CurrentNumber, String(4, "0"))
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim TextFileData As String, MyArray() As String, i As Long

    ' Open file as binary
    Open "FilePath" For Binary As #1

    ' Read entire file's data in one go
    TextFileData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , TextFileData

    ' Close File
    Close #1

    ' Split the data in separate lines
    MyArray() = Split(TextFileData, vbCrLf)

    For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray())
        ' Set CurrentNumber equal to the current max
        CurrentNumber = Val(Mid$(MyArray(i), 2))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
    Dim i As Long

    ' delete the old file
    If Not LenB(Dir(FilePath)) = 0 Then Kill FilePath

    'open the file for writing
    Open FilePath For Output As #1

    For i = 1 To CurrentNumber
        Write #1, "EM" & Format(i, String(4, "0"))
    Next

    'close the file (if you dont do this, you wont be able to open it again!)
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: which parts are you having a problem with? What does work, and especially what doesn't work? How does it behave and what did you expect?

Comment: What is the issue, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Independent of use binary mode...

open file for output as #1
print #1, "Some text"
close #1

open file for input as #1
line input #1, myvariable
close #1

msgbox myvariable

The flow is the same that you show, so what is the problem ?